# how to get distinct domain counts from Frame in h2o

Tags: h2o

In H2O, when we parse .csv file to `Frame` object how can we get distinct values count of a particular column(Vec).
For example, consider a column Fruits which has apple 3 times and mango 2 times. After parsing it to a frame, we can get distinct values using the `domain()` method, but how do you get distinct values along with their counts? In the example, I would be looking for:

```
apple,3
mango,2
```

Answer (score 5):

you're looking for h2o.table

From R:

```
   fr <- as.h2o(iris)
   h2o.table(iris[,"Species"])
```

From python:

```
   fr["Species"].table()
```